# Inject a method parameter value at runtime in an aspect

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj

I have defined an aspect that will wrap my @RestControllers:

```
@Aspect
@Order(1)
public class ControllerAspect {

    @Around("controllerinvocation()")
    public Object doThings(ProceeedingJoinpoint pj) throws Throwable{
          //before I would set MyObject values
         return pj.proceed();
    }
}
```

I want to make so that, if my controllers expose an instance of MyObject as parameter I fill it with value:

```
public void controllerMethod(MyObject obj, /* any other parameter */) { //of course obj is null now, how can I fill it?
```

How to do this? I know for sure it's possible as Spring already does it if I put, for example, an HttpServletRequest as parameter..will I need to also specify an annotation? Or can I do that based on parameter type only? Which is the most efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going for an `aop` based solution, then something like this would do the task

```
@Around( value = "execution( // your execution )" )
public Object doThings( ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint ) throws Throwable
{
    Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();

    for( Object arg : args )
    {
        if( arg instanceof MyObject )
        {
            MyObject sampleMyObj = new MyObject (); // Create the dummy value
            return joinPoint.proceed( new Object[] { sampleMyObj, // other args if any } ); // Pass this to the method
        }
    }

    return joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

Comment: you are writing "going for an 'aop' solution" - what would be another way of doing it? Where to read about it?